# Firestore geoPoint to Flutter nested objects

Tags: jquery, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I would like to create an object from a Firestore doc with a geoPoint. But I keep getting the error:
"Failed to get games: type 'GeoPoint' is not a subtype of type 'String?'"

This is my dataset on Firestore:

[image: Firestore doc]

This is how I query Firestore:

```
    Future<List<GameItem>> getGamesInRegion() async {
      List<GameItem> _returnList = [];
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('games')
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) {
        for (var gameItemSnap in querySnapshot.docs) {              
          _returnList
              .add(GameItem.fromJson(gameItemSnap.id, gameItemSnap.data()));
        }
      }).catchError((error) => debugPrint("Failed to get games: $error"));

      return _returnList;
    }
```

This is my GameItem Object:

```
import 'package:myproj/models/sk_location.dart';

  class GameItem {
    final String gameId;
    final String parentId;
    final String name;
    final int score;
    final SkLocation location;

    GameItem({
      required this.gameId,
      required this.parentId,
      required this.name,
      required this.score,
      required this.location,
    });


    factory GameItem.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
      return GameItem(
        gameId: id,
        parentId: parsedJson['parentId'] ?? '',
        name: parsedJson['name'] ?? '',
        score: parsedJson['score'] ?? '',
        location: SkLocation.fromJson(parsedJson['geoPoint']),
      );
    }

    toJson() {
      return {
        "gameId": gameId,
        "parentId": parentId,
        "name": name,
        "score": score,
        "location": location,
      };
    }
  }
```

And this is my SkLocation Object:

```
  class SkLocation {
    final double lat;
    final double lng;

    SkLocation({required this.lat, required this.lng});

    factory SkLocation.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
      return SkLocation(
        lat: parsedJson['lat'],
        lng: parsedJson['lng'],
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Geopoint object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint) in Firestore has two properties: `latitude` and `longitude`. In your code you are casting those fields by using `lat` and `lng`, that might be the cause of the problem,

So if you were to change your factory in the `SkLocation` class to the following it should fix the issue:

```
factory SkLocation.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return SkLocation(
        lat: parsedJson['latitude'],
        lng: parsedJson['longitude'],
    );
}
```